# error when trying to call API hosted on heroku from netlify app

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I have a React app deployed to Netlify and a spring backend on Heroku. When I access the react app and login, I get a CORs error,

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://glacial-sierra-91195.herokuapp.com/api/1.0/login' from origin 'https://elastic-mccarthy-484725.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is my first time trying to host an app online in this way. Reading up on this, it seems this is because I am using 2 different servers now for front and backend. But I was always using two different ones when testing, localhost:3000 for react and localhost:8080 for spring backend.

In my react package.json file I have this, `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` Which I thought was to point the api calls to the backend server. But is this actually solving this Cors issue also? If I change this to `"proxy": "https://glacial-sierra-91195.herokuapp.com/"` then all works fine when I run my react app locally on localhost:3000, but if I push to github and open it up via my netlify website, then I get a post error as it is trying to post to `https://elastic-mccarthy-484725.netlify.app/api/1.0/login` so using the netlify url rather than the heroku one where the backend is hosted from.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors) I have set global configuration to allow all controllers to have cross site requests.

in my webConfiguration class I added

```
@EnableWebMvc //For the class

@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**"); //Gives access to all endpoints
    }
```

I then updated my SecurityConfiguration class, (this is needed if using Spring security.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity //added
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }
    @Autowired
    AuthUserService authUserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint());

        http
                .cors() //added
                .and()//added
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/1.0/signup").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/1.0/login").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/1.0/users/{id:[0-9]+}").authenticated()
                    //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/1.0/management/users/delete/{id:[0-9]+}").authenticated()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

All works fine now.